# Scaffold-DbContext breaking change upgrading from EF Core 6 to EF Core 7

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-database-first

I have an entity framework model that I generated from a Postgres Database(database first) using `Scaffold-DbContext` for Entity Framework Core 6

The command I used to generate my model is:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "ConnexionString" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL -Context MyDBContext -Force
```

Now, I want to upgrade to Entity Framework Core 7. So I run the same query

The models I got are different : the relationships are now read only :

property generated with EF Core 6 : `public virtual ICollection<Utilisateur> Relation1 { get; set; }`

property generated with EF Core 7 : `public virtual ICollection<Utilisateur> Relation1 { get; } = new List<Utilisateur>();`

I couldn't find any documentation for this change

- Was this change intended ? I find it weird that the relationships are read only. I should be able to add a child entity
- Is there a way around it ? (I know that I can always use the hacky solution `myEntity.Relation1.ToList().AddRange(aNewList)` but that does not seam right)

Comment: "Adding a child entity" and "replacing the collection of all child entities" are very different things.

Comment: Check this strange explanation in [Customize the entity types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/templates?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#customize-the-entity-types)

Comment: Why would you ever want to set collection navigation property? Just call Add, Remove etc. Lack of setter only prevents you from doing Relations = ..., which you don't need anyway.

Comment: `myEntity.Relation1.ToList().AddRange(aNewList)` will not work for obvious reasons. If your problem is just that `ICollection` doesn't have the `AddRange` method, just iterate over `aNewList` and call the `Add` method: `aNewList.ForEach(e=> myEntity.Relation1.Add(e))`

Comment: Create extension method over `ICollection`: `void ICollection<T> AddRange<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> items)`. And your code will continue compiling.

Comment: In my code I have many places where I "replace the collection of all child entities". Is it bad ? I don't want to change this across all my code

Comment: It is bad for tracked entities.

Comment: When I replace the collection in EF6, the related entities get synchronized :
- If a related entity exists, it will be update
- If if does not exists, it will be added
- If it exists but was not specified in the new list, it get deleted
And it do this for all the hierarchy (related entity of related entity of related entity).
I want the same behaviour in EF7. I don't want to loop through all properties manually and add these conditions explicitly

Comment: @ihebiheb

Late to the show, but I had the same problem, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75422460/can-i-force-entity-framework-core-7-to-not-make-icollections-read-only

I think we can conclude that it has something to do with change-tracking, but the fact that it isn't documented as a breaking change is surprising. It took a lot of my time to find this out. Thank god for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update** : I regenerated my entities using EF 7.0.5 (without any customization) and now the setters are back again. So no need to customize the scaffolding for this

---

Like noted in the comments and in the [linked thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75422780/1546137), no one seems to understand the reasons behind this undocumented change. But if needed, here's how to make your collections mutable (I'll copy the response from the linked thread. I tried the steps below using `EF Core 7.0.3`)

You can customize the scaffolding since .NET 7 using [Custom Reverse Engineering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/templates?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) Templates.

1. In visual studio, `open the Package manager console`
2. As a default project, select the project from where you will generate your entities/context (Generally, it will be your Data Access Layer project). Let's call it `DalProject`
3. Place yourself under `DalProject` : `cd .\DalProject`
4. Install the required templates: `dotnet new install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Templates`
5. Generate the template files : `dotnet new ef-templates`

This will generate a folder named `CodeTemplates` that contains a folder named `EFCore` that contains 2 files `DbContext.t4` and `EntityType.t4` inside your DalProject

6. Update `EntityType.t4` file so that all collection navigations will be settable (find all `ICollection` mentions in the file). In my case, I found it in 2 places :

here :

```
if (navigation.IsCollection)
{
#>
    public virtual ICollection<<#= targetType #>> <#= navigation.Name #> { get; set; } = new List<<#= targetType #>>();
<#
```

and here :

```
#>
    public virtual ICollection<<#= skipNavigation.TargetEntityType.Name #>> <#= skipNavigation.Name #> { get; } = new List<<#= skipNavigation.TargetEntityType.Name #>>();
<#
```

Comment: Just wanted to confirm that this works (as I wrote in the linked thread).

Comment: thanks for the warning. Yes I tried it. It works perfectly. I added more details so it will be more clear