# Can I force Entity Framework Core 7 to not make ICollections read-only?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, scaffolding, .net-7.0, ef-core-7.0

Entity Framework Core 7 introduced a breaking change (although it is *not* listed in the breaking changes for EF Core 7): when defining model classes with scaffolding (`Scaffold-DbContext`), EF Core 7 now makes the `ICollection` properties read-only.

EF 6 code sample:

```
public virtual ICollection<PictureData> PictureData { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<PictureMetaData> PictureMetaData { get; set; }
```

EF Core 7 code sample:

```
public virtual ICollection<PictureData> PictureData { get; } = new List<PictureData>();
public virtual ICollection<PictureMetaData> PictureMetaData { get; } = new List<PictureMetaData>();
```

I have code that assigns to these properties, is there any way to force the `Scaffold-DbContext` to define these properties as not read-only? (And I don't want to change this manually...)

(And is there a reason for having these read-only?)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think the reason it's readonly is because they don't want you overwriting their proxy (if there is one).  There might be changetracking done that when you replace the collection is no longer done.  That's my guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can customize the scaffolding since .NET 7 using [Custom Reverse Engineering Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/templates?tabs=dotnet-core-cli). Install the required templates:

```bash
dotnet new install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Templates
```

Add them to your project (run from the project folder in terminal):

```bash
dotnet new ef-templates
```

Find `CodeTemplates/EFCore/EntityType.t4` and modify all collection navigations to be settable (find all `ICollection` mentions in the file). For example:

```
if (navigation.IsCollection)
{
#>
    public virtual ICollection<<#= targetType #>> <#= navigation.Name #> { get; set; } = new List<<#= targetType #>>();
<#
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it. What would the reason be to have them read-only by default? And why did they change it?

Comment: @user736570 tbh do not know.

Comment: @user736570 was glad to help! For readonly - maybe there are some internal benefits for change tracking.

Comment: You dont need the setter, you should use Add or Remove instead

Comment: Thanks @ErikEJ 
What would be the reason? Doe EF attach some events on Add and Remove that is used (maybe for change tracking as suggested by others)?
And why did it take until EF 7 for them to remove the setter?
I'm a bit concerned now that we may have issues in our code.

Comment: @user736570 I highly doubt that there breaking changes that have that deep effect so you need to be concerned. The only thing I can imagine - a bit better performance when using the collection methods to add or remove relations. If using setters on the relationship was such a big concern EF core for sure have mentioned that in the docs and even introduced an analyzer for that.

Comment: @GuruStron Yes, I'm not that worried. We have automatic tests, and no problems there.
It's very strange though that the "missing setter" isn't documented as a breaking change here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes

Comment: Actually, there is one more change. In EF 6 the ICollections were initialized as HashSets:

            PictureData = new HashSet<PictureData>();
            PictureMetaData = new HashSet<PictureMetaData>();

Now they are initialized as Lists. I have no idea of the effect of that.