# EF Core 7 Null Error and other on production

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-7.0, ef-postgresql

I develop a console app using dotnet core and ef core 7 for postgresql and MySql. During development, I found no problems or errors when querying with ef core7. But after I publish the console app and running on Linux OS, I error that only happen when query. For example:

```cs
var projects = dbContext.Projects
    .Where(w => w.Year > 2022)
    .Select(s => new {s.Id, s.Name})
    .ToList();
```

On my local development, there is no error, but when I publish it and run on server, I often got error like this:

```bash
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')
```

For now I just made all property nullable and problem solve, but it also really annoying because I need to change others code like cast from nullable to non nullable, or add error handler or default like `project.TotalDays?? 0`, etc

even though all models are generated using a scaffold.

What must be done so that what is produced at local development runs well or is the same as at the production level?

---

Complete error info

```
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')
   at System.ArgumentNullException.Throw(String)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[]) in C:\Users\myname\RiderProjects\ETL\ProjectTransaction\Program.cs:line 62
```

I just relized, I dev in Windows and run on linux, but the error still `C:\Users\myname\RiderProjects\ETL\ProjectTransaction\Program.cs:line 62`

---

Model generated by scaffold

```cs
public partial class Project
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    public string? Code{ get; set; }

    public string? Name{ get; set; }

    public int? TotalDays { get; set; }

    public int? TotalEmployees { get; set; }

    public DateOnly? StartAt { get; set; }

    public DateOnly? EndAt { get; set; }

    public int? IdZone { get; set; }

    public string? NameZone { get; set; }

    public int? Periode { get; set; }

    public int? Year { get; set; }

    public int? Month { get; set; }

    public int? Week { get; set; }

    public string? Status { get; set; }

    public string? Notes { get; set; }
}
```

and this my scaffold command

```bash
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=DB_IP;Port=5432;Database=ERPDB;User Id=XXXXX;Password=XXXXXXX;" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL --output-dir Erp/Models --context-dir Contexts --context DbContext
```

and this is the db context

```cs
public partial class DbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbContext()
    {
    }

    public DbContext(DbContextOptions<DbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>(entity =>
                {
        
                    entity.Property(e => e.EndAt).HasColumnName("end_at");
                    entity.Property(e => e.Month).HasColumnName("month");
                    entity.Property(e => e.Code).HasColumnName("code");
                    entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasColumnName("name");
                    entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("id");
                    entity.Property(e => e.TotalDays).HasColumnName("total_days");
                    entity.Property(e => e.TotalEmployees).HasColumnName("total_employees");
                    entity.Property(e => e.StartAt).HasColumnName("start_at");
                    entity.Property(e => e.IdZone).HasColumnName("id_zone");
                    entity.Property(e => e.NameZone).HasColumnName("name_zone");
                    entity.Property(e => e.Periode).HasColumnName("periode");
                    entity.Property(e => e.Year).HasColumnName("year");
                    entity.Property(e => e.Month).HasColumnName("month");
                    entity.Property(e => e.Week).HasColumnName("week");
                    entity.Property(e => e.Status).HasColumnName("status");
                    entity.Property(e => e.Notes).HasColumnName("notes");
}
```

Comment: Post the actual DbContext definition. That error most likely means `Projects` is null, possibly because the property isn't settable. `source` is the IEnumerable or IQueryable parameter in most LINQ operations

Comment: You should post the *full* exception text too, not just the message part. The full exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()` contains any inner exceptions and a stack trace that shows the chain of calls that resulted in the exception. In this case I suspect the stack trace includes a call to `Where`, which means `Projects` is null

Comment: Do you develop and test on Windows?

Comment: @vernou yes I develop and test on windows

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Update full exception, and you are right error on `Where`, but the projects not null, because it safe when I test in on my local. BTW I use the same database

Comment: I didn't say anything about the database. I said that `YourDbContext.Projects` is null because the property probably isn't settable. Post code that compiles and actually reproduces the problem (ie including the DbContext), not just the query

Comment: Aren't `DbSet` properties in DbContexts normally code-generated?  If that were a Property { get }, you'd be getting an error elsewhere when  you try to set it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, when they're settable. Code generation can't fill a read-only property. Googling for the error returns this as one of the possibilities

Comment: Why would code generation make an unusable property?

Comment: @RobertHarvey it didn't. The developer wrote that. We don't have an actual repro right now. *Perhaps* the OP used EF Core 8 tools and copied the code to a .NET 7 project? Perhaps `set;` was removed due to an IDE warning?

Comment: @yozawiratama: Show us the code from your `DbContext` class.

Comment: @RobertHarvey if this was an EF Core tool error all developers using scaffolding would run into this.

Comment: I very much doubt this is being caused by a property get.  Recall that this works fine locally, before the publish.

Comment: @RobertHarvey there are related SO questions from February 2023 like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74871400/scaffold-dbcontext-breaking-change-upgrading-from-ef-core-6-to-ef-core-7). It's possible there *was* an error back then that was fixed in 7.0.5

Comment: @RobertHarvey I added the DbContext and model, sorry I need to modify and delete some property naming

Comment: btw @RobertHarvey I publish with self-contained and produce single file, may be you need to know